# Koine Greek: Is the writing style of Luke the same as Acts?

Tags: greek, luke, acts, authorship

The authorship of the first two chapters and last two verses of Luke and Acts are contested because they were not part of Marcion's Canon. Does the writing style in those disputed texts match the sophisticated literary style of the non-disputed text?

Comment: Based on the style, layout, structure and vocabulary and the double negatives ("not a little", etc), the answer is "Yes".

Comment: Sounds like the beginning of an answer?

Comment: The first two chapters of Luke are likely an example of *mimesis,* wherein the author intentionally imitated the language of the style of the LXX to make this text sound "biblical." The classic study of Lucan imitation of the LXX, which can be related to the culture of *mimesis* is Eckhard Plümacher, *Lukas als hellenistischer Schriftsteller: Studien zur Apostelgeschichte* (SUNT 9; Göttingen: Vandenhoeck & Ruprecht, 1972) 38–72.

Comment: Interestingly, as Acts shifts into the Greek/learned/elite world, the writing style improves, but the author was somewhat "amateurish." Pervo (*Hermeneia*) commented that "His literary ambition exceeded his ability." See Richard I. Pervo, *Acts: A Commentary on the Book of Acts*, ed. Harold W. Attridge, Hermeneia—a Critical and Historical Commentary on the Bible (Minneapolis, MN: Fortress Press, 2009), 8.

Comment: Hi Dan. Well I'm not sure we should take our insights from someone named "Pervo"! But I guess Pervos are unavoidable these circles! But that does add new nuance to the question that I was not aware of.

Comment: I have heard from Rob Plummer, a Koine professor (https://dailydoseofgreek.com) that the style used in the powerful apocryphal story of the woman caught in adultery is written in a style easily attributed to the author of Luke-Acts. I would add, but certainly not to "John" (who is probably Lazarus, the disciple that Jesus loved)!!

Comment: @Ruminator also, it's notable that Pervo later says, "Negative reflection on style obscures a far from inconsiderable narrative gift. Luke is an accomplished storyteller who has learned many narrative techniques and how to deploy them with impressive skill. Although famed for notable stories, he is also able to forge these into a single, coherent narrative and thereby create (rather than simply report) a sense of historical movement" (p. 8). So it wasn't all critique.

Comment: @Ruminator it is an unfortunate, albeit fitting, name in this case (if you Google him, you'll see what I mean).

Comment: @Dan Oh my, talk about living up to one's name! HAHAHA!

Comment: Craig Keener deals with this in his Acts Commentary

Answer (score 1):

Marcion was branded a heretic in his own day and did not accept any New Testament writings except an abridged version of Luke & Paul's writings. (ie. he did not even accept any of the other gospels). He rejected the idea that the Old Testament God and Jesus' Father were the same being.

So I'm don't know that he can really be used as the basis for any real dispute among Christians.

> Early Christians such as Irenaeus, Tertullian, and Epiphanius claimed that Marcion's editions of Luke and the Pauline epistles were intentionally edited by Marcion to match his theological views, and many modern scholars agree.
> (Wikipedia article on Marcion, with footnote to Robert J. Wilkinson (5 February 2015). Tetragrammaton: Western Christians and the Hebrew Name of God: From the Beginnings to the Seventeenth Century)

In terms of non-Christian scholarship, the question doesn't seem to be raised there either.

When looking at source criticism of Acts, I can find no reference to Marcion's selection. The main areas of discussion are of whether chapter 1-15 and 16-28 are based on different sources (due to the sudden use of "we" beginning in 16). In terms of textual criticism it is between the Alexandrian and Western texts (the Western being longer and attested by ancient sources, but the shorter Alexandrian one being the one most English translations are based on, based on the theory the shorter original work is usually added to rather than the longer original work abbreviated).

> The common authorship of Luke-Acts is accepted by almost all.
> The reason for this is clear when one compares the two works:
> a. Both begin with a similar preface (Luke 1:1–4; Acts 1:1–5).
> b. Both are addressed to the same person, Theophilus (Luke 1:3; Acts 1:1).
> c. Acts 1:1 serves as a recapitulation of the material found in Luke.
> d. Acts begins where Luke leaves off temporally, i.e., at Jesus ascension (Luke 24:50–51; Acts 1:9–10).
> e. Acts begins where Luke leaves off geographically, i.e., in Jerusalem (Luke 24:52–53; Acts 1:9–10).
> f. Acts begins with the same situation with which Luke ends, i.e., the disciples waiting for the coming of the Spirit (Luke 24:49; Acts 1:4–5, 8).
> g. There is a clear parallelism between the arrangement of Luke and that of Acts: an introductory period typified by prayer (Luke 1:5–2:32; Acts 1:6–26) followed by the coming of the Spirit in fulfillment of prophecy (Luke 3; Acts 2), followed by a thematic sermon (Luke 4:14–30; Acts 2:14–40).
> h. Both share a common vocabulary, style, structure, and theological concern.
> [Stein, Robert H. Luke. Vol. 24. Nashville: Broadman & Holman Publishers, 1992. Print. The New American Commentary.]

So I would conclude that Luke-Acts has a consistent literary style (whether it would be termed "sophisticated" is debatable).

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: I'm wondering if your tip implies that I didn't follow the instructions well? If so, please let me know. I read them through and feel like I'm OK, though I did discuss how different groups (ie. Christian vs non-Christian) today might consider the question - which maybe is not correct?

Comment: No, your answer is fine. It is just my custom to help new users by guiding them to resources that will help them get the most out of the site. No harm.